# Job submission failed, the user <data lake analytics account name> does not have permissions to a subfolder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

> Job submission failed, the user *datalakeanalyticsaccountname*
>   does not have permissions to a subfolder in the /system/ path needed
>   by Data Lake Analytics. Please run “Add User Wizard” from the Data
>   Lake Analytics Azure Portal or use Azure PowerShell to grant access
>   for the user to the /system/ and its children on the Data Lake Store.

The data factory seems to
treat the "name" of the data lake analytics account as an user and complains about permissions.
I have U-SQL transform activity with Azure Data Lake Analytics linked service.

```
{
"name": "LsDataLakeAnalytics",
"properties": {
    "type": "AzureDataLakeAnalytics",
    "typeProperties": {
        "accountName": "<data lake analytics account name>",
        "authorization": "**********",
        "sessionId": "**********",
        "subscriptionId": "xxxxxxxx",
        "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

}

I'm a super user in the default Data Lake Store and I authorized the linked service with my organization credentials. I even checked my access to /system/ folder path and I got RWX access. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

On further investigation it was down to Firewall settings on Data Lake Store. When switched off the Firewall, Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA) was able to access Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS).

We need to further figure out how to have Firewall On in ADLS and give ADLA access to ADLS at the same time. Thanks.